# Building UIButton With Border Initialization

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to initialize a custom UIButton class, but I'm doing it wrong and not sure how to implement this. I built a custom UIButton class and initialized it in an IBOutlet. The button works fine but none of the properties that I set are displayed.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class WBCircleButton : UIButton {
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2

    }
}

class WBMainViewController: UIViewController {

var timeControl = WBTimeController()

var timer = NSTimer()

@IBOutlet weak var timeDisplay: UILabel!

//this doesn't work as expected ?????
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: WBCircleButton!


//********************************************
@IBAction func startTimer(sender: AnyObject) {

    timeControl.startTimer()

    startButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    let aSelector: Selector = "updateTimerDisplay"

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: aSelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}


//********************************************
func updateTimerDisplay () {
    timeDisplay.text = timeControl.timeLabelText
}

//********************************************
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

//********************************************
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't validate something. I created a Xcode Single View Application template project and did the following (check each step to see what is missing for you).

**In your project navigator:**

Create a new UIViewController class file, name it "WBMainViewController" and set this code in it:

```
import UIKit

class WBMainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: WBCircleButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        startButton.setTitle("Stop", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

}
```

Create a new UIButton class file in your project, name it "WBCircleButton" and set the following code in it:

```
import UIKit

class WBCircleButton: UIButton {

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: decoder)

        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
    }

}
```

**In Interface Builder:**

Select your UIViewController scene and set its class to "WBMainViewController" in the Identity Inspector.

Add an UIButton to your scene, set auto layout constraints to it and set your UIButton class to "WBCircleButton" in the Identity Inspector.

Select your ViewController scene and click on the "Show the assistant Editor". Be sure to display your ViewController code and drag your startButton IBOutlet on the UIButton in your Interface Builder scene.

Launch your project.

I was able to display this big button in my ViewController after launching my project in the simulator:

[image]

Comment: This worked great. I defined the custom button class in the viewController and once it was placed in a separate file, and attached, it displayed the properties. I didn't realize that defining the button class in the viewController wasn't the way to go.